# Foundation 6 modal flashes and closes

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

While consulting various documentation regarding Foundation 6's reveal modal, the attempt to start with the modal open on a given page fails: the modal flashes appears for a moment then disappears.

```
<div id='homeModal' class='reveal-modal' data-reveal>
  <h2>Welcome ...</h2>
  <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
</div>
```

which is preceeded by javascript. I have attempted a few variations, based on forum discussions (or varants thereof):

```
$(document).foundation();
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#homeModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
}
```

or  [according to the documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html#close)

```
$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#homeModal').foundation('open')
});
```

Given that the modal flashes, I hypothesize that the modal does fire, but immediately considers it ordered to close.

How can this behave according to normal expecation, i.e. it is opened on page load and the user closes it?